# How to integrate vLine Video Chat in MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, vline

How to integrate vLine Video Chat in MVC4 application?

https://vline.com/developer/docs/support

Answer (score 1):

We don't have an example for an MVC4 application, but if you take a look at [our examples for other languages](https://vline.com/developer/docs/examples), you should be able to get an idea of how to do it.

Basically, you need to generate an [authToken](https://vline.com/developer/docs/authentication) for your authenticated user and inject that as a JavaScript variable in the page that is displayed to the user. Your JavaScript in the page then uses the vLine API to log in to our cloud and make calls.

For example, [here's the page](https://github.com/vline/vline-node-example/blob/e7f039a466b03ccae2e89497315b837e98ca5f12/views/layout.html) from the node example that shows a call button for other logged-in users. Note that `jwt` and `serviceId` are enclosed in `<%= %>'; those are the values that are generated on the server and replaced before serving the page to the user.